# Is there a method to interpolate the volatility smile?

Tags: black-scholes, implied-volatility

I have a small question of interest. During my classes at the university I have learned about the Nelson-Siegel method to fit interest rate curves. With this method you are able to determine interest rates between two observed interest rate point. Is there something similar for the volatility surface?

One example see the picture below. I have the following volatility surface at time t, for maturity z and stock x. However I want to know the implied volatility for a plain-vanilla option with strike price 37.5 (for which I don't have data). Is there a common method in practice, that extrapolate a line between strike price 20 and 40, so that I can observe all the underlying implied volatilities?

[image]

Comment: I suggest "Smile interpolation and calibration of the local volatility model" written by Nabil Kahalè.

Comment: See [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44247/fitting-function-for-skew?noredirect=1#comment64330_44247).